# Prestashop 1.6 - Too long API request

Tags: web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to get the orders from a set of customers. I use the next API request:

```
http://example.com/api/orders?io_format=JSON&display=full&ws_key=mykey&sort=[id_DESC]&filter[current_state]=[19|15|18]&filter[id_customer]=[29100|29101|29102|29103|29104|29105|29106|29107|29108|29109|29110|29111|29112|29113|29114|29115|29116|29117|29118|29119|29120|29121|29122|29123|29124|29125|29126|29127|29128|29129|29130|29131|29132|29200|29201|29202|29203|29204|29205|29206|29207|29208|29209|29210|29211|29212|29213|29214|29215|29216|29217|29218|29219|29220|29221|29222|29223|29224|29225|29226|29227|29228|29229|29230|29231|29232|29233|29300|29301|29302|29303|29304|29305|29306|29307|29308|29309|29310|29311|29312|29313|29314|29315|29316|29317|29318|29319|29320|29321|29322|29323|29324|29325|29326|29327|29328|29329|29330|29331|29999]
```

The [id_customer] filter gets ignored and the web service returns orders from all the customers.

If I make the [id_customer] filter shorter, removing from 29100 to 29200, the filter works correctly (see example below).

```
http://example.com/api/orders?io_format=JSON&display=full&ws_key=mykey&sort=[id_DESC]&filter[current_state]=[19|15|18]&filter[id_customer]=[29200|29201|29202|29203|29204|29205|29206|29207|29208|29209|29210|29211|29212|29213|29214|29215|29216|29217|29218|29219|29220|29221|29222|29223|29224|29225|29226|29227|29228|29229|29230|29231|29232|29233|29300|29301|29302|29303|29304|29305|29306|29307|29308|29309|29310|29311|29312|29313|29314|29315|29316|29317|29318|29319|29320|29321|29322|29323|29324|29325|29326|29327|29328|29329|29330|29331|29999]
```

Is there a limitation in Prestashop API about the number of filtered elements or something similar?
And more important, how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the longer query, do you get any PHP error messages? Have a look at `<prestashop home>/webservice/error_log`.

Comment: No PHP error message, just the result but without the filters applied. If I print_r($_GET) I don't get the two filter parameters in the long query. For the short query print_r($_GET) is OK.
I'm thinking about Apache configuration, probably the http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestline. The problem is that my hosting provider don't want to modify this directive, so I will make a test in local environment.

Comment: Ok. Add any relevant information to your question. I was thinking of something related to a lack of memory at the PHP script. Something like `memory_limit` too low. You could try placing a `<prestashop home>/webservice/php.ini` file with something like `memory_limit = 512M`. The web service uses a lot of memory.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think in that case I should have get a PHP error like **"... memory exhausted"** but the webservice returns a correctly formed JSON. The problem is, the result ignores my filters and returns all the customers.
As soon as I can try the **LimitRequestLine** I'll update my comment.
Thanks for your help!